# How to add a new image to a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, assets

I'm working on the frontend part of a rails app. I had to add few images, so I added those images into app/assets/images directory.

I can access images that came with the app via /assets/[image name], but I can't access my new images. I tried

```
/assets/images/[image name]
/assets/[image name]
/[image name]
/images/[image name]
```

looks like there's a caching system behind, or I'm doing something incorrectly.

Please advise me.

Thanks,
Moon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use the `image_tag` or `asset_path` helper to compute the path to a named asset—see [Linking Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) from the Asset Pipeline guide.

You could also try a `rake tmp:clear` if you're using the default simple file-based rails cache to make sure nothing's being cached incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<%= image_tag "yourfilename.png" %>
```

Comment: Also, I moved my images over to vendor/assets/images. I had the same issue when my images were in app/assets/images. Hope it helps!